# Android JNI: convert cv::Mat to jbyteArray

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

I have C/C++ source code (run well on Windows) to convert an input frame to new frame.

Now i want to porting this C/C++ source code to my Android application to convert frame of device Camera2.

I will get continuous byte[] frame of Camera2 from Java app then input it to JNI to received converted byte new_frame.

So my flow in JNI must be:

1. Convert byte[] frame from Java to JNI jarrayByte
2. Convert jarrayByte to jyte*
3. Create new cv::Mat original from jbyte*
4. Convert input cv::Mat orignal to new cv::Mat converted using C/C++ function
5. Now, i need to convert back cv::Mat converted to jByteArray to return Java function => i'm stucking at this step

So my question is how to convert back cv::mat to jbyteArray to return Java layer of application?

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray
JNICALL
Java_com_xyz_NativeUtil_convertFrame(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                  jbyteArray yuvFrame) {
// convert jByteArray to jbyte*
jbyte* yuvByte = env->GetByteArrayElements(yuvFrame, 0);
// convert jbyte* to cv::Mat
cv::Mat frame_original_yuv = cv::Mat(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, yuvByte);
// convert YUV cv::Mat to RGBA cv::Mat
cv::Mat frame_original_rgba = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4);
cv::cvtColor(frame_original_yuv, frame_original_rgba, CV_YUV2RGBA_NV21);
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(yuvFrame, yuvByte, 0);
// convert frame
cv::Mat frame_converted = convert_frame(frame_original_rgba);
frame_original_yuv.release();

if (frame_converted .empty()) {
    frame_converted = frame_original_rgba;
}
frame_original_rgba.release();
// convert cv::Mat to jbyteArray
jbyteArray result = ???

return result;
```

}

My Java code:

```
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (image == null)
                    return;

                Image.Plane Y = image.getPlanes()[0];
                Image.Plane U = image.getPlanes()[1];
                Image.Plane V = image.getPlanes()[2];

                int Yb = Y.getBuffer().remaining();
                int Ub = U.getBuffer().remaining();
                int Vb = V.getBuffer().remaining();

                byte[] yuvFrame = new byte[Yb + Ub + Vb];

                Y.getBuffer().get(yuvFrame, 0, Yb);
                U.getBuffer().get(yuvFrame, Yb, Ub);
                V.getBuffer().get(yuvFrame, Yb + Ub, Vb);

                image.close();
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that you want to pass native `cv::Mat` object to Java and convert it to `Bitmap`.

In that case it is better to convert it to `jintArray` instead, so I will write an  example using that, but you can easily modify that code to use `jbyteArray` instead

Note that in that code I assume your `cv::Mat` has 4 channels (bgra), change that accordingly. If your mat is gray - set `r, g, b` to the same gray color and `a` to 255. If your mat is bgr - set `a` to 255.

```
jintArray matToBitmapArray(JNIEnv *env, const cv::Mat &image) {
    jintArray resultImage = env->NewIntArray(image.total());
    jint *_data = new jint[image.total()];
    for (int i = 0; i < image.total(); i++) {
        char r = image.data[4 * i + 2];
        char g = image.data[4 * i + 1];
        char b = image.data[4 * i + 0];
        char a = image.data[4 * i + 3];
        _data[i] = (((jint) a << 24) & 0xFF000000) + (((jint) r << 16) & 0x00FF0000) +
                   (((jint) g << 8) & 0x0000FF00) + ((jint) b & 0x000000FF);
    }
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(resultImage, 0, image.total(), _data);
    delete[]_data;

    return resultImage;
}
```

BGR case:

```
jintArray matToBitmapArray(JNIEnv *env, const cv::Mat &image) {
    jintArray resultImage = env->NewIntArray(image.total());
    jint *_data = new jint[image.total()];
    for (int i = 0; i < image.total(); i++) {
        char r = image.data[3 * i + 2];
        char g = image.data[3 * i + 1];
        char b = image.data[3 * i + 0];
        char a = (char)255;
        _data[i] = (((jint) a << 24) & 0xFF000000) + (((jint) r << 16) & 0x00FF0000) +
                   (((jint) g << 8) & 0x0000FF00) + ((jint) b & 0x000000FF);
    }
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(resultImage, 0, image.total(), _data);
    delete[]_data;

    return resultImage;
}
```

Gray case:

```
jintArray matToBitmapArray(JNIEnv *env, const cv::Mat &image) {
    jintArray resultImage = env->NewIntArray(image.total());
    jint *_data = new jint[image.total()];
    for (int i = 0; i < image.total(); i++) {
        // Note that you can use better gray->rgba conversion
        char r = image.data[i];
        char g = image.data[i];
        char b = image.data[i];
        char a = (char)255;
        _data[i] = (((jint) a << 24) & 0xFF000000) + (((jint) r << 16) & 0x00FF0000) +
                   (((jint) g << 8) & 0x0000FF00) + ((jint) b & 0x000000FF);
    }
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(resultImage, 0, image.total(), _data);
    delete[]_data;

    return resultImage;
}
```

And on java side

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ourNativeArray, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

**EDIT**

Considering that you have BGRA 4 channel image, here is how you would convert it to `jbyteArray`

```
jbyteArray matToByteArray(JNIEnv *env, const cv::Mat &image) {
    jbyteArray resultImage = env->NewByteArray(image.total() * 4);
    jbyte *_data = new jbyte[image.total() * 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < image.total() * 4; i++) {
        _data[i] = image.data[i];
    }
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(resultImage, 0, image.total() * 4, _data);
    delete[]_data;

    return resultImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not much experience about JNI converting so what do you mean with " but you can easily modify that code to use jbyteArray instead"? Only by replacing "jintArray" to "jbyteArray" ?

Comment: The thing is - I don't know why would you need byte array, so the problem is a bit unclear for me. It really depends on what you expect to see in the output array (you may expect jpeg or png data in it - how would I know that)

Comment: Thanks Dmitrii, i updated my question for full information. Could you advise me?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you Dmitrii, you are absolutely expert in this field. I merge your code to my program, build NDK then run application. Unfortunately my application is crashed with error message "A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9c840000 in tid 1619". I think it is because of my source code are not correct in somewhere. Could you take a look to my above JNI source code and give your comment? Do i need to release done object (bug, frame_original_) or my cv::Mat convert from YUV to RGBA is not correct? I'm really approviate your support.

Comment: You're welcome. If my code answered your original question - consider marking it as the accepted answer. Your segfault is out of the question's scope, therefore create a new one & add all necessary debug information (track line of code which causes that caused it using debugger or android log)

Comment: Sure, because your answer is totally correct. I found the error reason and fix it. Now my source code run like a charm. Thanks.